Analytically solving a couple of non-linear second ODE
I try to find an analytic solution for the following couple of non-linear second ODE in MA:
 eq1[t] := (1/(128*(2 + 3*t)^2))*(-16*2^(2/3)*(2 + 3*t)^(13/3)*f[t] - 8*(2 + 3*t)*(96 - 680*2^(2/3)*(2 + 3*t)^(1/3) - 3*k^2*(2 + 3*t)^4 - 3*2^(2/3)*t*(2 + 3*t)^(1/3)*(704 + 9*t*(66 + t*(10 + 3*t))))*f[t] - 3*2^(2/3)*(2 + 3*t)^(7/3)*(2^(2/3)*(2 + 3*t)^(10/3)*f[t] - 32*y[t]) + 256*(2 + 3*t)*y[t] - 64*(k^2*(2 + 3*t)^3 - 8*(160 + 3*t + 9*t^2))*y[t] +  4*2^(2/3)*(2 + 3*t)^(16/3)*Derivative[1][f][t] + 4*(9*2^(2/3)*t*(2 + 3*t)^(7/3)*(4 + 3*t*(2 + t)) + 8*(2 + 3*t)^2*(-6 + 2^(2/3)*(2 + 3*t)^(1/3)))*Derivative[1][f][t])
and:
y''[t] := eq2[t] 
where:
eq2[t] :=(1/(16*(2 + 3*t)^3))*(-18*(2 + 3*t)*(k^2*(2 + 3*t)^4 + 32*(-1 + 7*2^(2/3)*(2 + 3*t)^(1/3)) + 2^(2/3)*t*(2 + 3*t)^(1/3)*(692 + 9*t*(64 + 3*t*(3 + t))))*  f[t] + 16*(3*k^2*(2 + 3*t)^3 - 8*(478 + 3*t*(2 + 9*t)))*y[t] - 3*(2 + 3*t)^2*(9*2^(2/3)*t*(2 + 3*t)^(1/3)*(4 + 3*t*(2 + t)) + 8*(-6 + 2^(2/3)*(2 + 3*t)^(1/3)))*Derivative[1][f][t])
To find an analytic solution for {f,y} I simply used DSolve:
DSolve[{eq1[t] == 0, y''[t]== eq2[t] ,f[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {f, y}, t] // FullSimplify
But DSolve returns the same expression. So I wonder if there is anyway to solve these equations analytically in MA. Of course I can solve them numerically, but it seems the analytic solutions is not trivial. So any help is appreciated.

First you should correct syntax. Change eq1[t]:=to eq1 and eq2[t]:=to eq2. Unfortunately DSolve[{eq1 == 0, y''[t]== eq2  ,f[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {f, y}, t]  still won't evaluate

@UlrichNeumann.. I think because it is complicated and non-linear. Even I wonder if there is a way of approximation or so. I tried to extrapolate analytic solution from the numeric solution by NonlinearModelFit but the " fitted" function does not correspond to the numeric function solution, so I think it is not an accurate way.

In diff-eq terminology, it seems to be linear but no holonomic

@Dr.phy Which values takes parameter k?

@UlrichNeumann.. Yeah, the solution is a function of two variables  t and k , which can take arbitrary values, for instance [k,-2,2] and [t,0.1,10]
